# How can I write response body of HTTPS request to file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to write the content of the web page to a file. However I am stuck at file writing part. Because it gives me a type error.

```
import Control.Lens
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Network.Wreq

writeURIBodyToFile :: FilePath -> String -> IO()
writeURIBodyToFile filePath uri = do
  response <- get uri
  body <- (response ^. responseBody)
  BL.writeFile filePath body
```

Here is the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO BL.ByteString’ with ‘BL.ByteString’
Expected type: Getting
                 (IO BL.ByteString) (Response BL.ByteString) (IO BL.ByteString)
  Actual type: (BL.ByteString
                -> Const (IO BL.ByteString) BL.ByteString)
               -> Response BL.ByteString
               -> Const (IO BL.ByteString) (Response BL.ByteString)
In the second argument of ‘(^.)’, namely ‘responseBody’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: body <- (response ^. responseBody)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:
`body <- (response ^. responseBody)`

Should be:
`let body = response ^. responseBody`

To explain the type error you're getting: the compiler is saying `Couldn't match type ‘IO BL.ByteString’ with ‘BL.ByteString’`. So it's saying with the code you wrote it was expecting an `IO ByteString` but you gave it a `ByteString`. This is down to the `<-` operator in the `do` block. This, desugared, would look like `response ^. responseBody >>= \body -> <rest of code>`.

The type of `(>>=)` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. So the compiler thought you were saying that `response ^. responseBody` would have the type of `m a` or more specifically `IO a` (where `a` is `ByteString`).

Luckily we can use `let` in a `do` block and assign `body` that way :)